# Using only a rheostat on a LED ceiling panel light

Tags: led

I have a 40 watt 2'x2' led ceiling panel with a dimmable driver. With the purple and gray 0-10v circuit left open, the light operates at full brightness.

Considering the following ([Pathwayconnect.com: Best Practices for Dynamic 0-10VDC LED Lighting Control](http://www.pathwayconnect.com/index.php/downloads/reference/file/0-10VDC%20Best%20Practice%2008.14.2015.pdf)) "When the purple and grey wires are open (not touching each other or connected to anything else) the dimming signal will be 10VDC and the output of the driver will be 100%. When the purple and grey wires are shorted together (touching each other) the dimming signal will be 0VDC the output of the driver will be set to the minimum dimming level or the driver will drop in to “sleep mode” and turn off the LEDs completely."

In simplest form, applied to a single panel, would it be accepatable to connect a rheostat (approx 2K) across the purple and gray wires to use as a variable series resistor to transverse the range: short to nearly open?

Comment: There is nothing generically significant about the colour of wires. Electrons still flow the same and the insulation can break down at the same voltage. Grey or purple mean absolutely nothing however, a picture or schematic might. VTC.

Comment: This question is specific to the dimmable driver you have. You will need to post the details of that driver (preferably manual and/or datasheet, but at the very least the manufacturer and part number) in order for anyone to help you.  You can add these to your question by clicking "edit" in the bottom left corner of it.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322950/0-10v-digital-rheostat-for-led-dimmer/322977#322977 for details of operation of a similar power supply.

Answer (score 1):

In its simplest form, yes, this should work.

Assuming the article you referred to is correct in that the driver sources about 0.5mA, a 2K resistor between the wires would produce a voltage drop of 10V and should have the same effect as it not being there at all (i.e. not touching each other or not connected to anything else).